# CSS relative path in @font-face

Tags: css, font-face, relative-path

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE

```
-index.html
    -foo
      |-my.css
      |-bar.jpg
      |-qux.ttf
      |- ...
```

This is working (absolute path)

```
div.class {background: url(http://www.foobar.com/foo/bar.jpg);}
```

This is working (relative path)

```
div.class {background: url(bar.jpg);}
```

This is working (absolute path)

```
p.class {font-family: 'qux'; src: url(http://www.foobar.com/foo/qux.ttf) format('ttf');}
```

=> This **doesn't** work (relative path)

```
p.class {font-family: 'qux'; src: url(qux.ttf) format('ttf');}
```

Works well with `background`, but not with `@font-face`.

I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @Roy Thank you for improving my question and my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's solution of the problem is to edit the browserSync settings (baseDir).

Thanks